# How to regex c# string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string, and I am trying to extract only the content within the FUNC( ):

FUNC(strToExtract)

I'm having trouble in extracting it using Regex.Replace()

Kind help would be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you know the string will always start with "FUNC(" and ends with ")" then not using a regex is a lot cheaper:

```
string myString = "FUNC(strToExtract)";
string startsWith = "FUNC(";
string endsWith = ")";
if (myString.StartsWith(startsWith) && myString.EndsWith(endsWith))
{
  string extracted = myString.Substring(startsWith.Length, myString.Length - endsWith.Length - startsWith.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try something like this:

```
Regex regexp = new Regex(@"FUNC((.*))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = regexp.Matches(inputString);
Match m = matches[0];
Group g = m.Groups[0];
```

Edit: removed the escaped () in @"FUNC((.*))"

Comment: Didnt work. I succeeded in doing egex.Replace("FUNC(foaksdokfakosdfko)", @"FUNC\((.*)\)", "$1")

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test it. And I thought you should escape the () from the FUNC method.
Happy you find the solution ;)

Comment: I don't think this is going to work for the following 2 reasons: 1) the brackets should be escaped appropriately, 2) the closing bracket will be matched by `.*` because the matching is greedy and so the bracket at the end is never matched. EDIT: perhaps the brackets don't need to be escaped when using @ .. just guessing

Comment: They do still need to be escaped.

Comment: Won't a regex on "FUNC ..." always return the value of FUNC?  I think he wants the value within the braces, if you want to compare the FUNC, you'd do the <= pre-look thing for FUNC( but not actually return the FUNC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string input = "Func(params)";
string pattern = @"\w+\((.+?)\)";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
string result = m.Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The parentheses must be escaped, otherwise they'll be interpreted as a regex group. The `.+?` will match at least one character and is not greedy, so it won't match more than necessary if multiple matches exist in the same input. The use of `\w+` makes the pattern flexible enough to handle different function names, not just "Func."